# Why am i getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature at runtime?

Tags: java, maven, jackson, yaml, jackson-databind

Trying to use  jackson 2.12.2 to generate some yaml files. My pom file contains the following jackson artifacts

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I compile fine but at runtime I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:655)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:567)
```

the exception occurs on the following line

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
```

I don't know what dependency I am missing, the code compiles without error. We are on an isolated network without access to the internet working from a sparsely populated nexus repository so I have to add each dependency to the repository. Bonus points if you can explain to me how I can figure this out on my own as I expect the unresolved runtime dependencies to plague me further.

I just checked using mvn depenency:tree and it looks like I am picking up an older version of the jackson yaml and core jars. I have no idea why this would be.

```
[INFO] +- io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:jar:10.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO] | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO] | \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.2:compile
```

Comment: How are you generating your jar with maven? Is it a *fat*-jar, i.e. it contains all the needed dependencies?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError: means when class loader try to load it from library it not able to find it .. check the jar file which you have created .

Comment: No I am not building a fat jar. I am running from within intellij.

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example? Show your whole pom file and your whole dependency tree for example.

Comment: I found the problem, one of the child poms was calling out the older version.

Answer (score 1):

OK so what happened is intellij asked me if I wanted to include a dependency when I added the YAMLFactory and I said yes. So it added the 2.8.11 dependency. Apparently YAMLFactory does not exist in 2.12.2. fyi I was relying on the tutorial at https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-yaml-files-in-java-with-jackson/ for code samples. I changed all the jackson artifacts to be 2.8.11 and the code now runs as expected.

Comment: Never use that IntelliJ feature again ^^